# XCOPY only files from a parent folder and from all its subforlders to a new folder in Windows?

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste, robocopy, xcopy

I was searching a lot of times how to copy all the files of different extensions from a folder and all its subfolders to a new folder without copying the folders itself using **Batch File**. I mean **ONLY FILES**.

I have a very massive(nested) directory structure I mean folder inside folders. I tried **Robocopy** but it didn't work. Then I found a code having **XCOPY**. I also tried **C#** but it takes too much time to complete.

If you have any other suggestion please recommend here.

Comment: What OS, what files? You should think of this as two steps: identify the files to move, then move them. This way means the method matters less, and you have more control over what is selected. Also, there are questions here going back a long time about how to move files of one type, so your research isn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with **PowerShell** if you're on anything resembling a modern Windows sytem.
The simplest version of what you're asking:

```
$source = 'C:\Users\source'
$dest   = 'C:\Users\destination'
$filter = '*.txt'

Get-ChildItem $Source $filter -recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $dest
```

To filter items by date, you pipe the results of [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) to [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) (aliases: `Where`or`?`) before piping to [`Copy-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1).

```
$Cutoff = [DateTime]'3/1/20'
Get-ChildItem $Source $filter -recurse |
   Where CreationTime -gt $CutOff |
      Copy-Item -Destination $dest
```

The [date-related properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/working-with-dates-in-powershell/) of an IO.FileSystem object are:

- CreationTime
- LastAccessTime
- LastWriteTime

You can use any of the [Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1).

For a recurring operation, you'll probably want to calculate the cutoff from the current date:

- Since Midnight: `(Get-Date).Date`
- Last 24 hours:  `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)`
- Midnight, day before `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date`

Comment: its working thanks, i can't upvote bcz i have only 1 rep.
but what if we want to copy files from a certain date ? as i did in my answer below...

Comment: by creationTime

Comment: Yes its working, thanks...
is there any way to run this code after every 24 hours?just like we run batch file in windows schedular

Comment: Hven't worked with that personally, but yes, have seen posts about [running PowerShell tasks through Task Scheduler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38580.windows-task-scheduler-configure-to-run-a-powershell-script.aspx). First step is saving the code in a .ps1 file, I know that! :D

Comment: i tried just like this and it worked
```Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\afnan\Desktop\source' '*.txt' -recurse | Where CreationTime -gt '06/08/20' | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Users\afnan\Desktop\destination'```

Answer (score 0):

Then I found a solution, and I think its very easy and fast then any other method.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "source=C:\Users\source"
SET "dest=C:\Users\destination"
SET "FileList=*.txt"

SET "dupCnt=1"

FOR /R "%source%" %%A IN (%FileList%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%%~NXA" (
        XCOPY /F /Y "%%~FA" "%dest%\" && IF EXIST "%%~FA" /Q /F "%%~FA"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :DupeRoutine "%%~FA" "%%~NA" "%%~XA"
        )
    )
GOTO :EOF

:DupeRoutine
IF EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" (
    SET /A dupCnt=%dupCnt%+1
    CALL :DupeRoutine "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%~1" "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" /Q /F "%~1"
    SET "dupCnt=1" 
    )
GOTO :EOF
```

Here is another thing, if you want to copy files after a certain date then put date inside this query like this:

**On line 11**

`XCOPY /D /D:06-05-2020 /F /Y "%%~FA" "%dest%\" && IF EXIST "%%~FA" /Q /F "%%~FA"`

**On line 23**

`IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" ECHO F | XCOPY /D /D:06-05-2020 /Y /F "%~1" "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" /Q /F "%~1"`

The date is in this format **MM-DD-YYYY**, also you can add other files extensions in **FileList=**